# Why does apt-setup-udeb not get configured?

Tags: 14.04, server

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 14.04 and am currently stuck on this error:

> INFO: Menu item 'apt-setup-udeb'  succeeded but requested to be left unconfigured.

At that point the installer stops. I am presented a menu where I can choose which step of the install to execute next. If choose to install GRUB and then reboot I can boot and log in. But I don't have all the software I wanted, and `apt` won't install any additional software.

What might be the reason `apt-setup-udeb` won't be configured during install?

My search for explanations lead me to some very old Debian bug reports which did not help me understand the problem and one [deleted question](https://askubuntu.com/q/376527/284919) which I cannot read.

Comment: Did you check the md5 or sha256 of the iso. It might be a corrupted iso.

Comment: @CedaEI I always verify the checksum before starting the installer. I just verified the checksum again just to be sure the iso didn't get corrupted in the meantime. The checksum is still correct.

Comment: I do have no idea other than that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I was installing Debian from an hard drive
At the beginning of the installation, for loading the data from the hard disk I had to mount it in the cdrom folder, by running the command:

`mkdir cdrom && mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /cdrom`

Then the installation got stuck at `Configure the package manager`

This is my `syslog`, as you can see it's the same error

```
main-menu[218]: INFO: Menu item 'apt-setup-udeb' selected
apt-setup: /usr/lib/apt-setup/generators/50mirror backed up
main-menu[218]: INFO: Menu item 'apt-setup-udeb' succeeded but requested to be left unconfigured.
main-menu[218]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
main-menu[218]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
main-menu[218]: INFO: Menu item 'save-logs' selected
```

**Solution**

So, I think that there are two things that you can do:

1. Since you are using Ubuntu, you can do what user832809 said, and try to run `d-i anna/choose_modules apt-cdrom-setup`
2. If it is not working, if you are using Debian and/or if you mounted the hd with the installation image in the `cdrom` folder, unmount it with this command:

   `umount /cdrom`

I hope it works, I spent a lot of time to figure this out

Comment: `umount /cdrom` worked for a reluctant Debian 11 install on a Raspberry Pi 4 (see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=282839&p=1780292#p1780292)), so I just wanted to say thanks for figuring that one out.

Comment: @Akeo you are welcome :) 
I've spent really a lot of time before figuring this out, I'm glad that my answer is helpful!

Comment: `umount /cdrom` worked here too when I got stuck during debian 10 netinst, you saved my day, thanks a lot, `@yes sure`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the same bug found in this question:
[Ubuntu preseed exits after package manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969179/ubuntu-preseed-exits-after-package-manager)

This is caused by previous bug ([apt-cdrom-setup not loaded during lowmem netinst install](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=476614)) on Debian installer, that it seems to persist, despite it said fixed.

You need to find a way to explicitly load the apt-cdrom-setup module in your installation method.
If you use a preseed file try with:

```
d-i anna/choose_modules apt-cdrom-setup
```

Comment: It's been a long time and I no longer recall what hackish workaround I used to get around the problem. But it sounds about right that the problem had to do with the cdrom setup somehow not working for me.