# Ubuntu preseed exits after package manager

Tags: system-installation, preseed

I'm trying to do an unattended install of Ubuntu 17.04. I have a preseed file that I'm incorporating into the cd-rom and this seems to be working fine up to a point.  However, after the package manager portion runs, the preseed just exits back to the main-menu.  I then have to choose **Finish Installation** and then the preseed continues to the end and reboots.  My question is - Why is the preseed exiting at this point and how can I make it continue to the end?

The only clue I have from the logs is this line here but not sure what it means...

```
Oct 25 17:24:42 main-menu[280]: INFO: Menu item 'apt-setup-udeb' succeeded but requested to be left unconfigured.
```

preseed file:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target sed -i \'s/quiet splash/console=tty1 console=ttyS1,115200n8/g\' /boot/grub/grub.cfg

d-i partman/early_command string umount /media                                                      
d-i preseed/early_command string anna-install parted-udeb                                           
d-i preseed/early_command string i=`parted /dev/sda print| tail -n2 |head -c 2 |tail -c 1`; while [ $i -ge 3 ]; do echo "parted /dev/sda rm" $i; i=$((i-1)); done            

d-i keyboard-configuration/variant select English (US)                                              
d-i console-keymaps-at/keymap select us                                                             
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us                                                     
d-i debconf/language string en                                                                      
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US                                                            
d-i debian-installer/language string en                                                             
d-i time/zone string America/Los_Angeles                                                            
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us                                                     
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false                                                          
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us                                                              
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string COTS-ETS                                                             
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select eno1                                                             
d-i passwd/root-login boolean false                                                                 
d-i passwd/user-fullname string diag User                                                           
d-i passwd/username string diag                                                                     
d-i passwd/user-password diag insecure                                                              
d-i passwd/user-password-again diag insecure                                                        
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true                                                     
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false     
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true                                                                    
d-i debian-installer/language string en                                                             
d-i debian-installer/country string US                                                              
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8                                                      
d-i localechooser/supported-locales multiselect en_US.UTF-8                                         
ubiquity partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true                                                 
ubiquity partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true                                                   
d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select biggest_free                                   
d-i partman/unmount_active boolean true                                                             
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true                                       
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish                                                          
d-i partman/confirm boolean true                                                                    
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true                                                        
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true                                                         
d-i mirror/protocol string ftp                                                                      
d-i mirror/ftp/hostname string us.archive.ubuntu.com                                                
d-i mirror/ftp/directory string /ubuntu/                                                            
d-i mirror/ftp/proxy string                                                                         
d-i mirror/country string US                                                                        
d-i apt-setup/multiverse boolean true                                                               
d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true                                                               
d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true       
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none                                                                      
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

I think this is the relevant logs when preseed exits:

```
Oct 25 17:24:42 main-menu[280]: INFO: Menu item 'apt-setup-udeb' selected
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> SETTITLE debian-installer/apt-setup-udeb/title
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> CAPB backup progresscancel
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 multiselect backup progresscancel align escape plugin-detect-keyboard plugin-terminal
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS START 0 1200 apt-setup/progress/title
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS INFO apt-setup/progress/setup
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 10 apt-setup/progress/setup does not exist
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> SUBST apt-setup/progress/fallback SCRIPT setup
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: Adding [SCRIPT] -> [setup]
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS INFO apt-setup/progress/fallback
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> GET apt-setup/multiarch
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 i386
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS SET 100
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> GET mirror/protocol
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 ftp
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> GET debconf/priority
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 high
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> GET debian-installer/locale
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 en_US.UTF-8
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> DATA debconf-apt-progress/preparing type text
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> DATA debconf-apt-progress/preparing description Please wait...
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS INFO debconf-apt-progress/preparing
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 in-target: Reading package lists...
Oct 25 17:24:42 in-target: 
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS SET 200
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS SET 200
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS INFO apt-setup/progress/mirror
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> GET apt-setup/use_mirror
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> SET apt-setup/use_mirror true
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 value set
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> METAGET apt-setup/use/netinst_old description
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 10 apt-setup/use/netinst_old doesn't exist
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS SET 300
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 apt-setup: /usr/lib/apt-setup/generators/50mirror.ubuntu backed up
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> PROGRESS STOP
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> CAPB backup
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 multiselect backup progresscancel align escape plugin-detect-keyboard plugin-terminal
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> GET debconf/priority
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: <-- 0 high
Oct 25 17:24:42 main-menu[280]: INFO: Menu item 'apt-setup-udeb' succeeded but requested to be left unconfigured.
Oct 25 17:24:42 debconf: --> X_SAVE
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/localechooser/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Choose language
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/brltty-udeb/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 10 debian-installer/brltty-udeb/title doesn't exist
Oct 25 17:24:43 main-menu[280]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/console-setup-udeb/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Configure the keyboard
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/cdrom-detect/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Detect and mount CD-ROM
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> GET preseed/file
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 file:///mnt/iso/ubuntu-server.seed
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/file-preseed/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Load debconf preconfiguration file
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/driver-injection-disk-detect/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Detect virtual driver disks from hardware manufacturer
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/load-cdrom/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Load installer components from CD
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/ethdetect/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Detect network hardware
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/netcfg/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Configure the network
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> GET preseed/url
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> GET rescue/enable
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 false
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/user-setup-udeb/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Set up users and passwords
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/clock-setup/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Configure the clock
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/disk-detect/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Detect disks
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/partman-base/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Partition disks
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> GET live-installer/enable
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 true
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/live-installer/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Install the system
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/apt-setup-udeb/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Configure the package manager
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> GET live-installer/enable
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 true
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/pkgsel/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Select and install software
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> GET grub-installer/skip
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 false
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/grub-installer/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/nobootloader/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Continue without boot loader
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/finish-install/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Finish the installation
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/cdebconf-priority/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Change debconf priority
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/cdrom-checker/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Check the CD-ROM(s) integrity
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/save-logs/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Save debug logs
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/di-utils-shell/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Execute a shell
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> METAGET debian-installer/di-utils-reboot/title Description
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 Abort the installation
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> GET preseed/url
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> SETTITLE debian-installer/main-menu-title
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: <-- 0 OK
Oct 25 17:24:43 debconf: --> CAPB
```

Comment: I think this is the same problem I'm having....
https://askubuntu.com/questions/818468/why-does-apt-setup-udeb-not-get-configured

Comment: After much trial and error I finally found the problem.  I looks like apt-cdrom-setup was not being loaded and as a result was halting on this step.  I loaded the module through anna and it resolved the issue for me.  

I found the clue in this old bug report.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=476614

It says the bug is fixed but it seems that it isn't.

Comment: d-i anna/choose_modules apt-cdrom-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I finally found the solution. The apt-cdrom-setup was not being loaded and as a result was halting on this step. I loaded the module through anna and it resolved the issue for me. I found the clue in [this old bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=476614).

It says the bug is fixed but it seems that it isn't.

```
d-i anna/choose_modules string apt-cdrom-setup
```

Comment: looks like the datatype is missing before apt-cdrom-setup, probably `string` or `multiselect`